# Is there any downside to using different apps for different servers (Rails and Node js) on Heroku?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, node.js, heroku, socket.io

I wrote a real-time web app that consists of the following:

Rails to serve the web pages (listens on port 80)
Nodejs to handle real-time logic (listens to port 8888)
So on a particular page served by my rails app, the JS will use socket.io to establish a connection to my nodejs instance to allow real time http push.

I will have to deploy separate apps for different servers (Rails and Node js). 
Is this a good solution (having multiple apps on Heroku)?
Will this affect performance and will there be any extra costs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do the same with a Python and node apps. The two downsides I can see, which are **not** really big cons so far as I am currently concerned, are:

1. If you want to prevent dyno idling you have to have at least 2 dynos per app, which means a little more cost. You can circumvent that by "pinging" (on the http level) each of your apps at least once an hour. Say from pingdom, or any other service that offers that for free. One app could even ping the other.
2. The communication between your apps isn't "as direct" as you may want it to be. That is: it is not thru a local interface. I don't share state between my apps (no Redis, no DB, no amq), and the communication between them is RESTful. So my Python app has to go thru the Heroku http router to get to my node app (that is: it has to go to `my-node-app.herokuapp.com`). This adds just a little bit of latency (which I don't really care about), and just a little bit of complication to my code: my Python and node apps now have a share secret in order to authenticate my Python app to my node app. This, to prevent "the general public" from contacting my node app.

Overall, as I said, I think that's a fairly decent solution.

Comment: How much latency does it cause, because I dont want any latency at all. I might need to share DB as well

Comment: In the order of milliseconds. If that is *really* a problem for you then you should consider using a shared resources such as Redis.

Comment: I just noticed I may have made a grammatical error in my original response. Just to be clear: these are *not* big downsides, as far as I am concerned. They are worth it, when the alternative is writing all of your Ruby logic in node just to have one app.

Comment: The alternative is using Pusher or PubNub, but it's paid but again its about the same cost as deploying 2 apps

Comment: Should I user Pusher or PubNub as an alternative? ----Nitzan Shaked?

Comment: I can't say, I've never used them. If they fits your needs I don't see why not.

Comment: One more thing, I need to poll for changes in DB, can I do that using multiple apps (share same DB between 2 apps)? --@Nitzan

Comment: Yes you can. Why poll? Why not write to the DB thru a service that will notify the "pollers"? Via pubsub/redis?

Comment: How can I share models and database between them? What if I want them to be pushed using the same git repo?--Need help urgently